# Building android AOSP 4.2.2 in ubuntu 14.04 gives error

Tags: android, android-source

I tried to build the AOSP following the android parent site "https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html".

Steps :
a) source build/envsetup.sh
b) lunch
c) I selected "full-eng"
d) Then make -j4
I have configured the cchache as well. Some error with switch.pm also I got, then I resolved it as well but after this error I am not getting anything. I can see the userdata.img and ramdisk.img file in the out folder. I dont see the system.img file.
And it throws this error. Anythigh else I missed, let me know.

### I got this error :

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext: Index: 1, Size: 2
at com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:46)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:344)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:487)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:387)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.compress(Dominators.java:136)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.eval(Dominators.java:160)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.run(Dominators.java:229)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.make(Dominators.java:90)
at com.android.dx.ssa.DomFront.run(DomFront.java:90)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.placePhiFunctions(SsaConverter.java:298)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:52)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:99)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:73)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
... 14 more
...while processing onQueryComplete (ILjava/lang/Object;Lcom/android/internal/telephony/CallerInfo;)V
...while processing com/android/phone/CallNotifier.class
```

---

What am I missing here? Please help me out as I can am not able to proceed further then this state.

### Environment :

Linux Ubuntu 14.04

JDK 1.6.0

### AOSP branch for 4.2.2

Comment: We need more to go on then this, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Just simple make command

Comment: add that to your question :)

Comment: @Jeet Did you find any solution!?